# Updating SeekBar in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView where each item represents a podcast that can run up to 90 minutes.  Selecting an item will display a SeekBar and start streaming in the audio from a URL using MediaPlayer.

I could use some pointers on how to handle maintaining the state of the SeekBar after it scrolls off the page and then scrolled back into view.  I know that views are recycled and I've read that caching views in the adapter is a bad idea so I'm just wondering what other options there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that views are recycled and I've read that caching views in the adapter is a bad idea

It's a bad idea to cache *all* your Views, except via the recycling mechanism. Caching one `SeekBar`, or even a row containing a `SeekBar`, won't be that big of a problem. Caching 1,000 rows is where the trouble lies.

So, I'd note which `position` is the one for the playing podcast. In your `getView()` implementation in your adapter, if the requested `position` is the one for the playing podcast, use your cached row. Otherwise, go through normal recycling.